# adding css class to the selected tab in next and previous tab jquery tab

Tags: jquery

I want to add css class to the currently selected tab content so when i click on the next button the css of the currently selected tab content should be changed.

I have tried the following code but it is not working:

```
 $("#tab-div").tabs();

    $(".next-tab").click(function () {

        var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option","selected");
        $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("current");
        $(this).find("a").addClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
     });

    $(".prev-tab").click(function () {
        var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("current");
        $(this).find("a").addClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="prev-tab">
<a href="#" title="Previous">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div class="next-tab">
<a href="#" title="next">&nbsp;</a>
</div>    




 <div id="tab-div">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#tab1" class="current">New Group</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">For Companies</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="current">
</div>
 <div id="tab2">
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: nevermind, you changed your html quite a bit since I posted. It really seems like a poor way to setup your tabs - I would consider rethinking entirely. You should be setting up a tabs class which handles all this, including hiding/showing of the tabs content divs and settings/removing the selected/current class.**

```
$(".next-tab, .next-tab").on('click', function() {
    $('#tab-div a').removeClass("current");
    $(this).find("a").addClass("current");
 });
```

would change the current class to whatever you clicked. This doesn't seem like a great way to set up your tabs though, and I'm also not sure about the .tabs() method without knowing more.